# How to setup a temporary git-repo for testing?

Tags: java, git

Hi i want to test this function below with unit-testing:

```
public String cloneRepo(String sshURL){
  System.out.println("Cloning repository "+ sshURL);
  String cloneStatus;

  try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("git clone " + sshURL + " ./cloned-repo");
    cloneStatus = "Cloning OK";
  } catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.print("Could not clone repo.");
    cloneStatus = "Cloning Failed";
  }

  return cloneStatus;
}
```

And i want to create a temporary git-repo to test is it possible.
Because if you run a the tests again the tests are going to fail!
Because of the cloned repository already exists is it possible to create
a temporary Git-repo under run-time?

Comment: why not just create the repository in ```/tmp/.myrepo-123``` (and replace those 123 with 3-10 digit random generated number, or just timestamp)? also, I don't see problem with your approach, you just need to make sure to delete the repository after the test is done

Comment: how about as mentioned earlier on delete the repo once you're done working with it.